# How to use Guava's ClassToInstanceMap<B>?

Tags: java, guava

I try to work with Guava's `ClassToInstanceMap<MyObject>`.

I want to have my clients to use a method `addMyObject(MyObject)`, so I tried to write these methods:

```
private final ClassToInstanceMap<MyObject> instances = MutableClassToInstanceMap.create();

public void addMyObject1(MyObject o) {
    instances.putInstance(o.getClass(), o);
}

public <O extends MyObject> void addMyObject2(O o) {
    instances.putInstance(o.getClass(), o);
}
```

But naturally, none of these two methods compile.

So, how to use this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know for sure that `o` is an instance of `MyObject`, you don't really need to use the type-safe `putInstance` method. You could just use the standard `put()`:

```
private final ClassToInstanceMap<MyObject> instances = MutableClassToInstanceMap.create();

public void addMyObject(MyObject o) {
    instances.put(o.getClass(), o);
}
```

The `ClassToInstanceMap` will do a runtime check on the instance's type anyway.

That said, I'm interested in a way to do this using the type-safe method. Maybe some Java generics magic :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, you can narrow the Class type using

```
o.getClass().asSubclass(MyObject.class)
```

Comment: That's indeed an interesting path, but unfortunately, it doesn't compile as well because `asSubclass` doesn't return a `Class<T>` but a `Class<? extends T>`, which is my initial problem.